# How to run the same function (but class changes) on multiple IDs jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery("#box1").focusin(function() {
   jQuery(".grid_location1").show();
   }).focusout(function () {
   jQuery(".grid_location1").hide();
});

jQuery("#box2").focusin(function() {
   jQuery(".grid_location2").show();
   }).focusout(function () {
   jQuery(".grid_location2").hide();
});
```

HTML

```
    <input type="text" name="homepage_grid_box_1[box1]" class="box" id="box1"> 

    <div class="grid_location grid_location1"> </div>
```

This repeats for every ID I have on the page i.e there is 15. I feel this cannot be the correct way to go about this and instead there has got to be a more efficient method. I wasn't sure if a loop with a counter would work and had a go but it wasn't working.
Any ideas?

Comment: what does your HTML look like? Do your elements have classes?

Comment: The best would be to use the `class` attribute instead of `id`. There is rarely ever a good reason to have `id` values like "box1", box2", ...

Comment: Ideally, your HTML has a bunch of `<div>`s or other separator elements where each contains a box and its grid_location element. If that's the case you can target the separator elements and `.each()` on them, then associate each box with the grid_location. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/v74gacjq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better abandon the use of incremental id values like "box1", "box2", ...

Instead use a class "box" and assign that to those 15 box1, box2, ... box15.

For the same reason, incremental classes like "grid_location1", "grid_location2" are to be avoided. Just call them "grid_location". The context of where they are used, should be enough to isolate those that relate to a certain box element.

Either the box element *contains* the corresponding "grid_location" element(s), or you should create a container element (like a `span`) with a particular class ("container") that contains *both* one "box" element and the corresponding "grid_location" element(s).

Now that you added the HTML to your question, it is clear that those elements do not have a common parent, but are siblings. You can make it work with [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) as follows:

```
jQuery(".box").focusin(function() {
    jQuery($(this).next()).show();
}).focusout(function () {
    jQuery($(this).next()).hide();
});
```

A more reliable approach is to add container elements (with class "container"), like this:

```
<span class="container">
    <input type="text" name="homepage_grid_box_1[box1]" class="box"> 
    <div class="grid_location"> </div>
</span>
```

And then do:

```
jQuery(".box").focusin(function() {
    jQuery(".grid_location", $(this).closest(".container")).show();
}).focusout(function () {
    jQuery(".grid_location", $(this).closest(".container")).hide();
});
```

Comment: Hi I have added HTML to my question. Essentially the box is and input and the grid-location a div under it. So your solution is not working unfortunately.

Comment: That is why I mentioned the container element. Did you add it? Anyway I updated my question in light of the HTML you included in your question.

Comment: Perfect Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

you can use with comma seperated id's

```
jQuery("#box1, #box2, #box3").focusin(function() {
 jQuery(".grid_location1").show();
 }).focusout(function () {
 jQuery(".grid_location1").hide();
});
```

Comment: Please note that the show and hide methods point to different classes in OP's code.

Comment: he needs to change it, if you note the title. he is asking only for `same function` on multiple id's

Comment: There is a `(but class changes)` as well

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt but that added only after my answer. just 5 mins ago

Comment: Thanks for your Response Syed I should of made it clearer and have updated my question.